# Using {%with to define a url in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

Simple question, how can I use django's `WITH` to store a url in a template variable.

```
url={% url 'pro_img_next_page' name|encode_url  images.next_page_number %}
```

currently it is like that.

```
<a href="{% url 'pro_img_next_page' name|encode_url  images.next_page_number %}"> Click</a>
```

I want to store that in variable `href` so that i can use it like the following,

```
<a href="{{href}}"> Click</a>
```

Anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use `with` in this case, because `url` allow syntax {% url ... as var %}, so in your case:

```
{% url 'pro_img_next_page' name|encode_url  images.next_page_number as href %}
```

Some caveats:

- The scope of the variable created by the as var syntax is the {% block %} in which the {% url %} tag appears
- This {% url ... as var %} syntax will not cause an error if the view is missing.

Comment: In my html i did like this {% url 'pro_img_next_page' name|encode_url  images.next_page_number as href %}  and on the next line i typed, {{ href }} ---- so there is nothing in href variable. am i doing somthing wrong, or there is any closing tag also?

Comment: Wrap the `href` in any html tag, for example `p`

Comment: This {% url ... as var %} syntax will not cause an error if the view is missing (from official docs) try adding a {% if href %}....

Comment: However I am a bit concerned that you use a filter ; not 100% sure that a variable is then set...